# Motivation to consider a specific compact set to get uniform bounds on the derivatives of a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, inequality

In the text "Function Theory of One Complex Variable Third Edition" by Robert E. Greene and Steven G. Krantz i'm having trouble understanding how the bounds were derived from the compact set $E_{r}$ and what their purpose are in $\text{Corollary 3.5.2}$, the initial proof to the Corollary is developed in $(2)$, while the corollary in question is discussed in $(1)$. Also throughout the proof my comments and insights of the tools used can be seen in the sections titled $\text{Interjection}$, also $\text{Interjection (0.2)}$ is where my understanding begins to fail and where the key specifics of my question can be found

$(1)$

$\text{Corollary (3.5.2)}$

If $f_{j},f,U$ are holomorphic and $f_{j},f \rightarrow U$ with $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ then for any integer$K\in \big\{0,1,2,3.. \big\}$ we have in $(1.2)$

$\text{Remark}$

$U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$

$(1.2)$
$$(\frac{\partial}{\partial_{z}})^{K} f_{j}(z) \rightarrow (\frac{\partial}{\partial_{z}})^Kf(z)$$

uniformly on compact sets.

$(2)$

$\text{Proof of Corollary (3.5.2)}$

Let $E$ be a compact subset of $U$. Then there is an $r >0$ such that, for each $z \in E$, the closed disc $\overline{D(z,r)}$ is contained in $U$. Fix such an r. Then the set

$$E_{r}=\overline{\Bigg(\bigcup_{z \in E}D(z,r) \Bigg)}$$

compact subset of $U$.

$\text{Interjection (0.1)}$

My understanding the construction of the Compact Subset $E_{r}$ is to allow one at least at the global level to use compactness arguments to allow for the uniform convergence of $(\partial / \partial_{z} f_{j}(z))$.In summary at an intuitive level for the subset $E_{r}$ to be compact one takes $\overline{\Bigg({\bigcup_{z \in E}D(z,r)} \Bigg)}$ to from $E_{r}$.Which means we have a set that is not "too large" in which we can have functions defined on $E_{r}$ for one to have Cauchy criterion for $\partial / \partial_{z}f_{j} \rightarrow \partial / \partial_{z}f(z)$ uniformly on $E_{r}$.

For each $z \in E$, we have from the Cauchy estimate that:

$$\left| (\frac{\partial}{\partial_{z}})^{K} (f_{j_{1}}(z)-f_{j_{2}}(z))  \right|\leq \frac{k!}{r^{k}}\sup_{|\zeta -z| \leq r} |f_{j_{1}}(\zeta) - f_{j){2}}(\zeta)| \leq \frac{k!}{r^{k}}\sup_{\zeta \in E_{r}}|f_{j_{1}}(\zeta)-f_{j_{2}}(\zeta)|.$$

So far all $z \in E$, we see that

$$\left| (\frac{\partial}{\partial_{z}})^{K} (f_{j_{1}}(z)-f_{j_{2}}(z))  \right| \leq \frac{k!}{r^{k}}\sup_{\zeta \in E_{r}}|f_{j_{1}}(\zeta)-f_{j_{2}}(\zeta)|.$$

$\text{Interjection (0.2)}$

I'm having trouble on why the author used the Cauchy Estimates and what does it have to do with convergence how did he derive estimates for each closed disc in $E_{r}$ ?